# React-Native TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, redux, react-redux

I'm learning React-Native. I'm recreating Uber. I'm using Google Maps API.

Basically my app is like that:

[image: Selecting Location]

After, I got this error:
[image: error1]

And when i go to in 'get a ride' page, I got these errors;

[image: get-a-ride-error1]
[image: get-a-ride-error2]

Here my code pages;

[image: 'map.js']
[image: 'HomeScreen . js']
[image: NavSlice . js]
[image: store . js]

It can be looking a bit complicated, but I would be appericate if you could help me.

Thanks a lot from now!

I tried to deleted node modules and reinstall. It did not work.

I tried to updated packages, it did not work as well.

I tried to print location to my console in my homescreen page. When I did, it was like

```
`...
OnPress ={
  console.log(data);
  console.log(details);
}
...`
```

In my console, I can see the data. According to this, origin.location.lat and origin.location.lng supposed to work, but it did not.

Comment: Try to add `if(!origin?.location) return null` on `Map.js` line 13 (only for debugging)

Comment: When i add this, I faced same error for origin.location. On the other hand, I tried to write if(origin===null) I also saw same error "undefined is not a function" with white screen. Anyway, thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I have examined my project again and again.

Finally, I fixed it. Here the answer, I supposed to write as 'reducers', instead of 'reducer'.

I finger crossed this'll help the others in future!